# wss not working in https but ws works in http apache2 ubuntu

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04, websocket

My websocket setup works in http. But if I enable ssl(lets encrypt) and change the `ws://` to `wss://`, browser throws this error.

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://xx.yy.xx.yy:5001/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

**Javascript:**

```
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://xx.yy.xx.yy:5001');
```

I then enabled these apache modules: `proxy_http`, `proxy_wstunnel`, `proxy_balancer`

And added these lines in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
ProxyPass / ws://xx.yy.xx.yy:5001
ProxyPassReverse / ws://xx.yy.xx.yy:5001
</IfModule>
```

Got a 500 Server Error.

Though I had no idea how this proxy thing works, just given a blind try. Please correct my mistake, help me to fix this. Thanks.

**Server details:**

- Apache 2.4.18 running in AWS EC2 ubuntu instance.
- public ip : xx.yy.xx.yy
- private ip : aa.bb.aa.bb

**Websocket setup:**

I use private ip for back-end(php) connection and public ip in front-end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I fixed it myself. I changed my javascript into:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://domain.com/ws/');
```

Enabled proxy modules by running the following command in terminal,

```
sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_balancer proxy_wstunnel proxy_http
```

Added these lines in my Apache virtualhost config file(`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf`)

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass "/ws/"  "ws://domain.com:5001/"
```

Restarted apache service. And the websocket started working in https.

Comment: Facing the same issue, Not able to set connection over wss(failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out). Have you set the domain for backend and where you are configuring the proxy? is it in frontend virtualHost?

Comment: Can you share the full configuration of your apache2?

Comment: I added the proxypass in this file.
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf

Comment: You need to enable the following modules and restart apache service.

sudo a2enmod proxy proxy_balancer proxy_wstunnel proxy_http